# How do I solve $\log_{10}(X^2+3x)=1-log_{10}(x-3)$? Note this is a final exam problem in a basic algebra class.

Tags: polynomials, logarithms

Basic math takes me to $x^3-9x-10=0$, but what then? Note easy to throw into Wolfram Alpha or something, but how about this in a final?

Comment: Could you explain how you got to $x^3 - 9x - 10 = 0$? By the way, if you are taking a final exam, are you allowed to discuss it on the internet?

Comment: The equation $x^3-9x-10 = 0$ is correct, although it would be nice to more details on your attempt. In addition, I hope you are not attempting to use this site to cheat on the final exam. We do not tolerate that sort of behavior.

Comment: Did you learn about cubics or depressed cubics in your class?

Comment: I should have clarified, this is a problem from an old exam, so no cheating going on!  The class did not discuss how to solve cubics in any detail.

Comment: Also, this is from a European school, so final exam is covering multiple years of study. While equations solving is covered early (quadratic), later years go into elementary calculus. Still, I am not sure how to solve this one.

Answer (score 3):

Ok. Since you are just trying to learn from an old exam, then I'd happily help you out.

Your first step looks good. Basically, you moved $\log_{10}(x - 3)$ to the left, and got $\log_{10}(x^2 + 3x) + \log_{10}(x - 3) = \log_{10}(x^3 - 9x) = 1$, from which you deduced $x^3 - 9x = 10$. Good.

So the next step is to solve the cubic equation $x^3 - 9x - 10 = 0$. While there is the general Cardano-Tartaglia formula for solving cubics, I doubt that's expected in an algebra class.

In a classroom setting, usually the cubic equations are simple - most likely one of the roots is $0, \pm 1, \pm2, \pm 3$. Just check all of them. For $x^3 - 9x - 10 = 0$, it turns out that $x = -2$ is a root:

$(-2)^3 - 9 \times (-2) - 10 = -8 + 18 - 10 = 0$.

So now we know that $-2$ is a root. That means $x + 2$ is a factor of $x^3 - 9x - 10$. Using, say, long division, you can factorize $x^3 - 9x - 10 = (x + 2) (x^2 - 2x - 5)$.

Now you just need to solve $(x + 2)(x^2 - 2x - 5) = 0$. One root is $x = -2$, as we already found. You get the other roots by solving $x^2 - 2x - 5 = 0$, which are $1 + \sqrt{6}$ and $1 - \sqrt{6}$.

Finally, plug them back into $\log_{10}(x^2 + 3x) = 1 - \log_{10}(x - 3)$ to make sure they make sense. (You need to make sure $x^3 + 3x > 0$ and $x - 3 > 0$. I think that rules out $x = -2$ and $x = 1 - \sqrt{6}$.)

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. And yes, the general formula is definitely out of scope.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$x^3-9x-10=x^3+2x^2-2x^2-4x-5x-10=\\
x^2(x+2)-2x(x+2)-5(x+2)=\\
(x+2)(x^2-2x-5)$$

Comment: Thanks, cool approach, but difficult to generalize!

Comment: @ice-stu to be honest, I plotted the polynomial on Desmos, noticed that $-2$ was a root, and then solved the equation $$x^3-9x-10=(x+2)(x^2+bx+c)$$ for the constants $b$ and $c$. Once I found that $b=-2, c=-5$, I went back to find a way to factorize the polynomial from scratch

Comment: @ice-stu but yes, in general, factoring polynomials by hand is tricky